# Proving symmetry on a regular 2n-gon

Tags: contest-math, combinatorial-proofs

> Given a regular polygon of $2n$ edges, we color each edge black or white (with $n$ of each color). Prove that there exists a diagonal that divides the polygon into two sections such that all the black edges on each section correspond to a white edge on the other side, directly across from the diagonal, and vice versa.

How should I do this? Pigeonhole?

Comment: @RossMillikansorry, a typo. I had been working with the hexagon case, and because I was thinking about it I must have slipped up while writing the title. it is now fixed.

Comment: Is this diagonal required to be a diagonal that passes through the center of the polygon? If not, what does "directly across" mean in this context?

Comment: @runway44 I wasn't sure if I was misunderstanding the correspondence condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding the problem condition properly, I don't think this is true.

Given a regular $2n$-gon, there are $\binom{2n}n$ ways to color its sides black and white. However, if we fix a diagonal that should satisfy the above property, we only have $2^n$ colorings of the $2n$-gon that it can "cover" (i.e. the coloring satisfies the condition with this chosen diagonal) -- once you choose the way to color all sides on one side of the diagonal (each side can be black or white), all sides of the other half of the $2n$-gon are determined. There are $n$ ways to choose the diagonal, so you have at most $n2^n$ colorings of your $2n$-gon for which there exists a diagonal that satisfies the above condition. This implies that $n2^n\geq \binom{2n}n$, which is false for $n\geq 4$.

Comment: A small counterexample for the octagon is with edges colored cyclically as WBBWWWBB

Comment: yes, my conjecture appears to be wrong :( how can I request to lock this topic ?

Comment: @JJM A question on math.stackexchange can't be locked, but if you think this answers your question you can accept this answer and the question will show as having been resolved.

Comment: @JJM Your "conjecture"? Your question never stated the claim as a conjecture. It's tagged as contest math, and stated as a fact, so you've basically **lied** to us by omission! Lying to the people that are trying to help you is unwise!